# Java Memory Model, volatile, and synchronized blocks accessing non-volatile variables

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Given the following snippet of Java 8 Code which turns a Supplier into a caching Supplier which invokes the underlying Supplier only ever once and returns the cached value henceforth:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
private final static class SupplierMemoBox<T> {
  private Supplier<T> supplier;
  private T value;
}

public static <T> Supplier<T> memoizing(@Nonnull final Supplier<T> supplier) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(supplier, "'supplier' must not be null");
  final SupplierMemoBox<T> box = new SupplierMemoBox<>(supplier, null);
  return () -> {
    if (box.supplier != null) {
      box.value = box.supplier.get();
      box.supplier = null;
    }
    return box.value;
  };
}
```

This code is not at all designed for concurrent access. The memoizing supplier returned by the `memoizing` method could be accessed in parallel by two separate threads running on two processors.

In order to make this thread safe one could synchronize on the `box` object like so:

```
public static <T> Supplier<T> memoizing(@Nonnull final Supplier<T> supplier) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(supplier, "'supplier' must not be null");
  final SupplierMemoBox<T> box = new SupplierMemoBox<>(supplier, null);
  return () -> {
    synchronized (box) {
      if (box.supplier != null) {
        box.value = box.supplier.get();
        box.supplier = null;
      }
      return box.value;
    }
  };
}
```

Now I am wondering, since `SupplierMemoBox.supplier` is not marked `volatile` could it still happen that a thread entering the monitor on `box` read a stale variable for `box.supplier` or is that prevented from happening by the synchronization on the `box` object (i.e. does that make all accesses to member fields safe?). Or is there some other trickery which makes it safe, i.e. all reads happening from a thread which has entered a monitor are guaranteed to not be stale? Or is it not safe at all?

Comment: IMO it would be simpler to just make `supplier` and `T` as `final` and thus guarantee that they are properly initialized

Comment: @Eugene Both `box.supplier` and `box.value` are mutable by design. The given `supplier` is a (potentially very expensive in terms of execution time or allocation of other resources) factory method. The box object carries it's own reference to the supplier instead of the parameter `supplier` precisely so that it can be set to zero and therefore making it eligible for garbage collection (in case that factory object itself is an expensive object, i.e. binding a lot of resources such as memory). The check is on `box.supplier` instead of `box.value` as the supplier might very well return `null`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safety is defined by a transitive *happens-before* relationship as follows:

> #### [17.4.5. Happens-before Order](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.5)
>
> Two actions can be ordered by a happens-before relationship. If one action happens-before another, then the first is visible to and ordered before the second.
>
> If we have two actions *x* and *y*, we write *hb(x, y)* to indicate that *x happens-before y*.
>
> - If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then *hb(x, y)*.
> - There is a *happens-before* edge from the end of a constructor of an object to the start of a finalizer (§12.6) for that object.
> - If an action *x* *synchronizes-with* a following action *y*, then we also have *hb(x, y)*.
> - If *hb(x, y)* and *hb(y, z)*, then *hb(x, z)*.

The preceding section stated

> An unlock action on monitor *m* *synchronizes-with* all subsequent lock actions on *m* (where "subsequent" is defined according to the synchronization order).

which allows to conclude what the specification also says explicitly:

> It follows from the above definitions that:
>
> - An unlock on a monitor *happens-before* every subsequent lock on that monitor.
>
> …

We can apply these rules to your program:

- The first thread assigning `null` to the `box.supplier` does this before releasing the monitor (leaving the `synchronized (box) { … }`) block. This is ordered within the thread itself due to the first bullet (“If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then *hb(x, y)*”)
- A second thread subsequently acquiring the same monitor (entering the `synchronized (box) { … }`) block) has a *happens-before* relationship to the first thread’s release of the monitor (as concluded above, “An unlock on a monitor *happens-before* every subsequent lock on that monitor”)
- The second thread’s reading of the `box.supplier` variable within the `synchronized` block is again ordered with the acquisition of the monitor due to the program order (“If x and y are actions of the same thread and x comes before y in program order, then *hb(x, y)*”)
- Now the three relations stated above can be combined due to the last rule, “If *hb(x, y)* and *hb(y, z)*, then *hb(x, z)*”. This transitivity allows us to conclude that there is a thread safe ordering between the write of `null` to the `box.supplier` and the subsequent read of the `box.supplier` variable, both within a `synchronized` block *on the same object*.

Note that this has nothing to do with the fact that `box.supplier` is a member variable of the object we’re using for `synchronized`. The important aspect is that both threads use the same object in `synchronized` to establish an ordering that interacts with the other actions due to the transitivity rule.

But it is a useful convention to synchronize on the object whose member we want to access, as it makes it easier to ensure that all threads use the same object for the synchronization. Still, all threads must adhere to the same convention to make it work.

As a counter-example, consider the following code:

```
List<SomeType> list = …;
```

Thread 1:

```
synchronized(list) {
    list.set(1, new SomeType(…));
}
```

Thread 2:

```
List<SomeType> myList = list.subList(1, 2);

synchronized(list) {
    SomeType value = myList.get(0);
    // process value
}
```

Here, it is crucial for Thread 2 not to use `myList` for the synchronization, despite we use it for accessing the content, as it is a different object. Thread 2 still must use the original list instance for synchronization. This is a real issue with [`synchronizedList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List)), whose documentation demonstrates it with an example of accessing the list via an `Iterator` instance which still must be guarded by synchronizing on the `List` instance.

Comment: doesn't this rely on the fact that `box` instance is captured by the lambda expression so every thread will synchronize on the same instance? thus enforcing the *... both within a synchronized block on the same object* part? Also, to me, this in the JLS is mentioned as hb *consistency*

Comment: @Eugene `box` is always referring to the same instance for a particular memoizing supplier, obviously, you can’t reassign a `final` variable. Still, if you call the `memoizing` method twice, you get two suppliers using different boxes. So if you call the method more than once with the same original supplier, you get no guarantees regarding shared state within the original supplier. It is still important to understand which guarantees you get under which conditions.

Comment: I totally agree with that and it seems that your answer missed the crucial point, `volatile` is *not* required. Missed in the sense that I was expecting that to be the first sentence :)

Comment: @Eugene Well, the code example didn’t use `volatile` and I explained that (and why) the code example is thread safe. That implies that no change, including `volatile` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you modify `box` object's properties only inside `synchronized (box) {  }` it is thread safe. But be careful not to reassign the entire object value, i.e. `box = someValue` is not thread safe (a lot of people make this mistake for unknown reason).

Marking `box.supplier` as `volatile` would help in the case if you'd like to make non-blocking modification to it (i.e. without `synchronized` or similar locking).

Comment: I don't think that this is correct, some thread observing a non-null reference has no guarantees of observing non-null fields of that reference and this will be achieved by adding `volatile`

Comment: thread safety is guaranteed by happens before *consistency* btw; simply doing a `synchronized (box) {...}` is not enough, you have to do the other side (read of write) under the same lock for this to have the desired output and be correct from a JMM perspective

Comment: But was the question about consistency? I think it's only about thread safety. Consistency obviously is not guaranteed.

Comment: this is a very misleading comment, how can thread safety be without consistency to begin with?

Comment: It depends only on how you exactly define consistency. Please provide counter-example of code, when operating on `box.supplier` inside `synchronized (box) { }` (i.e. using monitor) does not guarantee the consistency of the value. I have strong doubts it possible.

Comment: this is not about your doubts or not, it has nothing to do with that, it's how JMM is set-up

Comment: How? You haven't provided any logic, only vague proclamations.

Comment: Your discussion is precisely what my question is about. I myself suspect that Eugene is right (which is why I asked this question in the first place). It would be great if you could give me some pointer to a spec which backs that up. Obviously I had hoped that there was a mechanism in the JVM which would basically access even non-volatile fields from a synchronized block as if they were volatile.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev hard to do that on the phone... I will later

Comment: @scravy that is exactly the reason I rarely answer these questions, it's a very complicated subject to begin with... You can start here https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/ as it seems very much related to your problem

Comment: @scravy why do you need that? If your field is accessed only inside `synchronized` block - it's safe, if it is accessed from some other place without synchronization - it's obviously unsafe.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev well, if you write in a synchronized block and later read without that same synchronized block (on the same lock), there are no guarantees that you will see the written values (the reference itself might not be null, but the contents might be null) - and I think this is what this question is about. That is why that `volatile` is required IMO

Comment: But here we have only the same lock on `box`'s monitor. Haven't we?

Comment: This says that on entry/exit to synchronised block the value is read/written to main memory - that would mean that `volatile` is redundant. https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_concurrency_synchronized2.shtml

Comment: Well, the 'unknown reason' is that they think they are synchronizing on the variable, when they are actually synchronizing on its value.

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak No, it means that `volatile` in conjunction with `synchronized` is redundant. Your citation isn't a normative reference in the first place, and in the second place it doesn't contain anything that supports your assertion. It doesn't contain the word 'volatile' at all. Even its title *What does variable "synchronization with main memory" mean?* is meaningless.

Comment: @AntonMalyshev I came to re-read my comments after Holger's answer - and you are right and I was wrong, I admit. For this example, `volatile` is not required, because once a certain `Supplier` is *shared* among different threads, there is a *single* box instance that they will synchronize on, thus hb consistency would be satisfied. On the other hand two threads calling `memoize` will obviously have no guarantees.